# $_POST variables coming through empty in IE7 for one subfolder

Tags: php, apache, post, internet-explorer-7

I've having trouble with $_POST variables not being received from forms within a PHP website.

To clarify the problem, I created this simple PHP script "POST_test.php":

```
<?
print "POST:<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
print "</pre>";
?>
<form method="POST" action="POST_test.php">
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes">
<input type="hidden" name="blah" value="1">
</form>
```

Let's say my Apache web root is folder "web_root", and my website folder is "websiteA". Putting the above script in "web_root/websiteA" and clicking the button in IE7 results in an empty $_POST array. Changing the name of the folder to "web_root/websiteA2" makes it start working, and it also works in other websites within the web root, such as "websiteB". There's no issue when using Firefox. Recently, NTLM authentication was enabled in our systems - I don't know whether this might make a difference.

Apache & PHP run on a server running (a somewhat old version of) Debian Linux.

I've also tried a ctrl-refresh of the page in IE, which didn't help, and neither did rebooting my PC.

**Update:** This forum post appears to describe the issue:
http://lists.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2006-March/027283.html

> 1. You cannot post any data to mixed 
>      NTLM and non-NTLM authenticated Web
>      sites. Microsoft Internet Explorer
>      requires NTLM authentication for all
>      visits to a website after you visit
>      one NTLM authenticated folder of the
>      website.

I can confirm this behaviour as follows:

When I visit http://mydomain/websiteA/index.php then http://mydomain/websiteA/POST_test.php $_POST is not populated by submitting the test page.

However, closing all my IE7 windows then browsing straight to http://mydomain/websiteA/POST_test.php shows $_POST IS populated by submitting the test page.

And one of the suggested solutions from the above linked forum post appears to be:

> The only way I have seen to get IE to
>   "forget" it has previously
>         NTLM-authenticated to a site is to send a 401 page status. This
>         effectively resets the IE authentication state.

Comment: Does it work if you change the `action` attribute's value to `?` ?

Comment: No - the URL just gets a ? on the end, but the result is the same.

Comment: This describes an issue with POST data with NTLM:
http://lists.rubyonrails.org/pipermail/rails/2006-March/027283.html
I will try some tests to see if the behaviour is similar

Comment: Are you able to pass `$_GET`s to the script~? could it be some sort of header truncation?~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.

It turned out that the problem was caused by a previous request to an unrelated page which made use of NTLM authentication like this (or similar):

```
<?php
  if (!isset($headers['Authorization'])){
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM');
    exit;
  }
?>
```

After that authentication was done, all $_POST data was received empty until IE was closed and re-opened. So far, I've worked around the issue by removing the above code and instead arranging for Apache to use NTLM within our Intranet (which sets the $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] variable). (Outside of our intranet, Apache authentication is still used).

Answer (score 2):

After working so hard i have found a trick for this problem. I used the whole ntlm authentication code as a include file in my php where the authentication is done and after that i can not make any form POST because of mixed-ntlm and non-ntlm issues which probably change the headers of the page.

so what you have to do is just include the same ntlm authentication codes at the begining every pages of your site and that will do the trick.

PROBLEM IS SOLVED... :)

Hope this helps a lot of people.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't so good if you have 3rd party apps you don't want to edit.

Comment: Appreciate your reply, but after researching a lot i ve found nothing so far.. other than this there is another solution by editing your windows registry value which in most cases is not acceptable or accessible by the user.

Comment: oh additional info.. somebody on google was talking about using cookies to store ntlm info and then send a 401 request to clear ntlm header and then use the cookie to get your desired info and that way when you clear up ur ntlm header it wont mess with POST method. but i vent tried it yet and cant even find the link again.. so if anybody tries and get any success please drop it here..

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill your "action" attibute because I don't think will actually work to leave this attribut empty in IE7.

Comment: Altering the script to have action="POST_test.php" gives the same result.

Comment: It usually works, but it has bugs in older versions of Safari. To workaround Safari, the `?` value could be used.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be worked around by disabling pre-authentication in IE. In the registry:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
```

On the Edit menu, Add Value name `DisableNTLMPreAuth` as a type `REG_DWORD` and set the data value to 1 (true).

For more information see [this bug report](http://www.websina.com/bugzero/kb/browser-ie.html) and [Microsoft KB 251404](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251404).

Comment: But if that only works at the client end, it's of no use to a web developer, right?

Comment: Seeing as the O.P. didn't actually state a question I see no reason for down-voting a workaround. In certain situations this workaround could be completely acceptable.