# IE8 has no $_POST data

Tags: php, post, internet-explorer-8

I am currently working on a login page, using Dreamveaver CS4.

My form looks like this (I have kept the code complete):

```
<form id="login" name="login" method="POST" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="loginnow" id="loginnow" value="go">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4"><img src="images/icons/login_icon.jpg" width="240" height="218" alt="login-icon"></td>
        <td>Benutzername</td>
        <td><input name="usern" type="text" class="fieldSm" id="usern"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Passwort</td>
         <td><input name="passwrd" type="password" class="fieldSm" id="passwrd"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" type="submit" class="button"   id="submit" value="Anmelden"></td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
         <td colspan="2"><a href="accounts/register.php">Hier </a>k&ouml;nnen Sie sich registrieren</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Now the php script checks for the hidden field

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['loginnow'])) {
   #  do some DW magic  ;)
   }
?>
```

With Firefox it works nicely and I can login properly, however is fails with IE8.

So, I was checking with:

```
<pre>
   <?php print_r($_POST); ?>
</pre>
```

This results in and empty array when using IE8. `$_REQUEST` only has only the PHPSESSID.

I have searched several sites, with no results or hints (mostly the issues are with graphical submit buttons).

If anyone could give a hint where my error is, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Have you checked if [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385341/post-variables-coming-through-empty-in-ie7-for-one-subfolder) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409847/posting-from-ie8-to-php-gives-blank-post) is what you are looking for?

Comment: `action="post"` should be lowercased. That probably won't cause the issue though, but `action="POST"` is still incorrect.

Comment: Remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from the form attribute and try again and let me know.

Comment: Right, because IE8 can't handle `multipart/form-data`? I agree that it's not needed here but it won't cause the problem.

Comment: Is it working after removing enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: 1st of all, thank you for your qucik response.No, it doeas not help

Comment: the lowercased `action="post"` does not solve the issue, sorry

Comment: I have changed the `action="post"`  to `action="get"` and it works !

Answer (score 0):

All of your pages are with the suffix php? are you using a mamp/wamp or real webserver with php?

Comment: I am using a QNAP SS-349Pro as webserver with MySQL, which is in the same network behind the firewall. All fildes use the .php suffix.

Comment: try to close your inputs ;-)  <input ... />