# Jquery Ajax Post type not working with zend framework IE 7/8

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

i am facing to a  weird problem in IE8/7 (as always), but this time it has came up-with zend framework.. below i have explained it ..

problem,

when i am using jquery ajax method in zend framework 1.X like below , if i use `'type: 'POST'`  then my zend controller will not detect the parameter values as it is, instead of it is displaying blank..

for example in my zend controller

```
`echo $this->_request->getParam('aData');` //echo nothing
```

but if  i USE type : 'GET' all parameters will display fine in my zend controller.

```
echo $this->_request->getParam('aData'); //echoing parameter values

$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/xhr_process/commentsave/",
            data: aData,
            success:function(aResponse){
                console.log(aResponse);
            }
        });
```

this is only coming in IE 8/7 other all browsers are working fine

appreciate thoughts !!

**UPDATE**

i have set CACHE to false it was not success

```
console.log(aData); Object { sCommentText="wewewewew", iComponent="1"}
```

Update 2

we are using NTML for authenticate

Comment: What version of jquery are you using... 2.0 dropped support for IE 8 and lower.

Comment: it is 1.7.2.. tnx for comment btw

Comment: do a console.log on aData what's it giving you in those browsers...

Comment: Please use ajax method post  : method : "post"

Comment: and type also :  type: 'POST'

Comment: its a json object like .. Object { CommentText="sometext", iComponent="1"}

Comment: Please paste it in your question. Is it really a "="?

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->getPost()` will contain nothing when you send it as post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You cannot post any data to mixed NTLM and non-NTLM authenticated Web sites. Microsoft Internet Explorer requires NTLM authentication for all visits to a website after you visit one NTLM authenticated folder of the website."

[$_POST variables coming through empty in IE7 for one subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385341/post-variables-coming-through-empty-in-ie7-for-one-subfolder)

Answer (score 0):

Notice the difference with the post and get methods (`getParam()` and `getPost()` methods):

using post:

```
echo $this->_request->getParam('aData'); //echoes nothing 
echo $this->_request->getPost('aData'); //echoes aData value
```

using get:

```
echo $this->_request->getParam('aData'); //echoes aData value
echo $this->_request->getPost('aData'); //echoes nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending data via ajax as a post variable you need to submit the data as either a urlencoded string:, also you need to set they type in your ajax call to `post`

```
  data: "aData="+aData
```

or a much similar way is as an object.

```
  data: {aData: aData}
```

jQuery will deal with encoding the data properly into the http post body.

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: "/xhr_process/commentsave/",
      data: {aData: aData},
      success:function(aResponse){
          console.log(aResponse);
      }
 });
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, i have tried this still no luck .. BTW we are using NTML for authentication purpose,perhaps  that could be the issue on this

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $this->_request->getParam('aData'); //echoing parameter values

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/xhr_process/commentsave/",
            data: {'aData':aData},
            success:function(aResponse){
                console.log(aResponse);
            }
        });
</script>

use this code it will work because i am also using this code for IE7 & 8
```